# AudioManager.isMusicActive() always returns true

Tags: android

I am writing some native code for a unity game. I want to know if the device is playing something when the game starts. If it is playing something, I want to mute the in-game sounds.

This is the function that I have in java class. I create context from unity side and pass that to this function.

```
public int CheckForDeviceSound(Context context)
{

      this.context = context;

      AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

     if(manager.isMusicActive())

     {

        Log.i("My activity", "Music player active");

        IsPlaying = 1;

        return 1;

    }

    Log.i("My activity", "Music player not active");

    IsPlaying = 0;

    return 0;

}
```

but isMusicActive() always returns true. I muted all game sounds for testing, launched the game but still got a true. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I would build a quick test application that checks only this and see if this is still returning true all the time.  Otherwise, it might be internal music in your application playing that is causing this to fire.

Comment: what exactly is internal music ? I mean, I haven't heard of anything like that.